# WARN about spark streaming by ver 2.0.1

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark, spark-streaming

When I try to use the latest Spark Streaming with checkpoint:

```
cfg = SparkConf().setAppName('MyApp').setMaster('local[3]')
sc = SparkContext(conf=cfg)
ssc = StreamingContext(sparkContext=sc, batchDuration=1)
ssc.checkpoint('checkpoint')
```

Then I got this repeatedly WARN :

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2016-10-11 10:08:02
-------------------------------------------
('world', 1)
('hello', 1)

16/10/11 10:08:06 WARN DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:546)
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2016-10-11 10:08:03
-------------------------------------------
('world', 1)
('hello', 1)
```

What is that? It looks like HDFS`s WARN

Is this a important information ?

I`m sure that there is not WARN with spark ver 2.0.0

Comment: I think the problem is the hadoop-hdfs.jar upgraded from v2.7.2 to v2.7.3.  Spark 2.0.0 uses 2.7.2 whereas Spark 2.0.1 uses 2.7.3

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi Yes! That is the reason. After copy  hadoop-hdfs-2.7.2.jar from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1 there is no WARN!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For completeness I moved my comment to the answer*

I think the problem is the hadoop-hdfs.jar upgraded from v2.7.2 to v2.7.3. Spark 2.0.0 uses 2.7.2 whereas Spark 2.0.1 uses 2.7.3